# Load AMD module in global scope in requirejs

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, global, amd

How can I load my AMD module and assign to globally so once it's load I can use without import(define).

**my-module.js**

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';
    console.log("in amd module...");
    return { a: 1 }; //need to assinge globally 
});
```

**app.js**

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';
    //MyModule shoud be accessed globally 
    return {};
});
```

**requirejs-config.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "my-module": "/my-module",
        "app": "/app.js"
    },
    shim: {
        "my-module": {
            // using some option to assine my module to gobally
            //global : "MyModule"
        },
        "app": {
            deps: ["my-module"]
        }
    }
});
// load app.js
requirejs(["app"], function (app) {
    console.log(amd);
    //MyModule shoud be accessed globally 
});
```

So, anyone has an idea how to load module globally?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you'd want to use AMD and put something on the global object, but assuming you've got your reasons...

In `requirejs-config.js` and your initial load function, require the module you need, alias it in the function callback, then add the module to `window`.

```
requirejs(["my-module", "app"], function (myModule, app) {
    console.log(amd);
    //MyModule shoud be accessed globally 
    window.myModule = myModule;
});
```